# Perform function with time interval SDL/c++

Tags: c++, timer, sdl

I want a function to be called every third second. In objective-c I would do like this:

```
NSTimer timer = [NSTimer timerWithInterval:3 sel:@selector(my_function)...];
```

How do I do this with SDL and c++? I've tried this:

```
SDL_TimerID myTimer = SDL_AddTimer(3,my_function(), NULL);
```

But I just get an error which says: No matching function for call to SDL_AddTimer.

What is wrong?

Comment: does the posted solution work?

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter should be 3000 since the documentation lists the units as milliseconds.

**edit:**
If the prototype doesn't match I get:

> ~/sdl$ g++ example.cpp -lSDL example.cpp: In function ‘int main(int,
>   char**)’: example.cpp:13:59: **error: invalid conversion from ‘void
>   (`*`)()’ to ‘SDL_NewTimerCallback {aka unsigned int (`*`)(unsigned int,
>   void*)}’** [-fpermissive] /usr/include/SDL/SDL_timer.h:109:37: error: 
>   initializing argument 2 of ‘_SDL_TimerID* SDL_AddTimer(Uint32,
>   SDL_NewTimerCallback, void*)’ [-fpermissive]

Which shows that the function prototype has to be:

```
unsigned int my_function(unsigned int, void * )
```

**This compiles:**

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

unsigned int my_function(unsigned int interval, void * param)
{
    return interval; // repeat the timer
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    SDL_TimerID myTimer = SDL_AddTimer(3000, my_function, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste the actual compiler error? I was expecting the my_function change  to fix it.  Anything compiler suggestions related to a mismatch will help also.

Comment: the thing I wrote in the question is the onlything I got

Comment: OK. Can you post the function prototype for my_function?

Comment: Like void my_function(int foo)  basically the first line of a small function

Comment: Check answer again, I have added an example of code that compiles.